# Updating directives scope in link function giving error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

HTML for the directive:

```
<div my-directive input-config=scopeObj1 current-pricing=scopeObj2 needs-refresh=scopeFlag1 > </div>
```

I have my directive set as follows:

```
  App.directive('myDirective',['', function(){
                    return {
                        restrict:'AE',
                        scope:{
                            inputConfig:'=',
                            needsRefresh: '=',
                            currentPricing: '='
                        },
                        transclude: true,
                        templateUrl: '...html',
                        link:function(scope,element,attrs){

                            console.log(scope);

                            if(scope.needsRefresh) {

                                    scope.currentPricing = data;
                                    scope.needsRefresh = false;
                                    console.log(scope);
                            } else {

                            }                       
                        }
                    };  
                }]);
```

Both the console.log show the same values and I have the following error

Non-assignable model expression: true (directive: myDirective)

And also if i put a breakpoint before the sencond console.log, I can see that the values are updated, but before printing they are resetting.

Any idea/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: By any chance are you using `needs-refresh='{{scopeFlag1}}'`?

Answer (score 0):

change the way you are taking the intputs on isolate scope

```
               scope:{
                        inputConfig:'@',
                        needsRefresh: '@',
                        currentPricing: '@'
                    },
```

because you are sending constant values rather than 2 way binding variables.

When you pass values in scope using `=` the directive expects the value to be a variable and not a constant. you currently what you are saying to directive is read $scope.true, where as what you actually intent is read the constant as is. hence use `=`.

you can read more about his [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2014/04/29/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals.aspx)

Comment: Actually for the sake of simplicity I changed all of them to true, they are actually objects/variables/flags that come from the parent scope. So I do need two way binding.

Comment: @NewUser can you share the JS part where you are initializing the variable to `true`